# fread - Read and skipping memory contents

Tags: c, linux

If I am reading a file as:

```
fptr = fopen(read_path, "rb");
fread(contents, size_in_bytes, count, fptr);
```

Let's say I want to read 4 bytes and then skip 4 bytes and then read 4 and so on. How can I do that? Specifically, how will I manipulate/advance the `fptr`?

Comment: fseek and you will ffind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An example using [`fseek`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/) :

```
FILE * fptr;

fptr = fopen("example.txt", "rb");
fread(contents, 1, 4, fptr);
fseek(fptr, 4, SEEK_CUR);
// ...
fclose(fptr);
```

Comment: +1, though I would use `SEEK_CUR` instead of `SEEK_SET` here, which would be easier than trying to keep track of an absolute position.

Comment: @Hasturkun You comment is relevant and interesting, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think the function you are looking for is [fseek](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/)

Answer (score 2):

If the amount to be skipped is small, you can always read it into a dummy and dispose of it:

```
char contents[SOME_SIZE];
char dummy[4];

fptr = fopen(read_path, "rb");
fread(contents, 4, 1, fptr);
fread(dummy, 4, 1, fptr);
fread(contents+4, 4, count-1, fptr);
```